# Interpretation of coefficients in linear regression: first difference of logs

Tags: regression, time-series

what is the correct interpretation of coefficients in time series regression when using first differencing on logs of the DV and in certain IVs.

FD(lnY)=c+beta1*ln(X)+beta2*FD(lnZ)

The log transformation was chosen to aim at elasticities. Differencing was chosen to achieve stationarity for some IV.

As FD(lnY) [FD=first difference] can be understood as e.g "growth rate", I now wonder if the elasticity notation holds in this case: e.g. that a 1% change of X leads to a beta1% change in FD(lnY)?

Does this further apply to coefficients of differenced logs of IVs, e.g. given by the beta2*FD(lnZ) term, which could be "inflation".Then, a 1% change in Z leads to a beta2% change of d(lnY)?

Thank you so much for clarification!

Best,
Sebastian